# How do I clone existed complicated rows to the work sheet using openxml

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I need to clone exists rows to the work sheet dynamically. ex. I wanna copy row 28, 29 and insert into 30, 31, or 32,33, or more maybe, it depends on the data rows.
from
[image]

to
[image]

How to do that in openxml dynamically?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The solution in this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701378/how-can-i-deep-clone-row-in-xlsx-file-using-openxml does not work for me

Comment: In what way does it not work? Be specific about what you have tried and what result you found.

Comment: I tried to copy rows, but the result rows' format was not correct. the merged cells were not arranged correctly.

Comment: I recommend you add that information to the question. Include your code and the resulting xml.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I use EPplus instead of OpenXML,
Just 2 lines to solve my problem.

```
private void AddRows(ExcelWorksheet sheet, int rowFrom, int colFrom, int rowTo, int colTo)
    {           
        sheet.InsertRow(rowFrom,2);
        sheet.Cells[28, 1, 29, 46].Copy(sheet.Cells[rowFrom, colFrom, rowTo, colTo]);
    }
```